# HTML template is not working even after converting it into wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have downloaded an HTML template and converted it into Wordpress theme.But I find following error
"Broken Themes

The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a stylesheet and a template.
Name    Description
stheme  Stylesheet is missing."

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Just have a look here, maybe the solution provided there solves your problem: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/stylesheet-is-missing-12

Comment: Thnks buddy..Stay in touch

Comment: And one more question.How do I change navigation menu from html to wordpress?

Comment: Maybe have a look here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-wordpress-theme-from-static-html-adding-navigation--wp-34032  ? Just guessing..

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when your wordpress template has missing stylesheet. 
Your template folder should contain style.css as main stylesheet in order to work properly.

```
Main files required for Theme

style.css
index.php
header.php
footer.php
page.php
single.php
images folder
css folder

Other files required for theme.
author.php
category.php
tag.php
put style.css in theme folder not in css folder inside your theme.
```

all your css declarations should come in style.css

Comment: I have done with it.Thanks :)

Comment: Hey if you did make my answer useful and give me ratings

Comment: Only `index.php` en `style.css` is required actually.