# How to convert a static html template to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am new to WordPress theme development.I need to know how to convert an html page to wordpress theme completely with theme option and how to create widgets for themes.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: We are not here to teach you how to use wordpress. Learn that on your own: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML template is not working even after converting it into wordpress theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582216/html-template-is-not-working-even-after-converting-it-into-wordpress-theme)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start developing themes is to look at the way existing themes are build and to look at the WordPress codex (as Marc suggested). If you follow the WordPress standards and get used to the system, WordPress is a very flexible platform for building websites.

Another thing: Google is your best friend :) Almost everything you want to do with WordPress has already been asked on Google.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Their are alot of tutorials online but I suggest starting with something simple like this free program from http://www.wpsiteconvertor.com/

Basicaly the whole gist of creating a wordpress theme (lets say you have one page and a style file) you would have to seperate that page into like 5 files minimum header.php, footer.php, index.php,you would also need to make style file changes and add a functions.php file. But take a look at that program above and you will see what kind of codes are added to a site to make a wordpress theme work.